# Instantiate an int within an if statement

Tags: c#

I want to be able to reduce the following code to fewer lines, as it's used several places:

```
int callID = getCallIndex(roomID);
if (callID >= 0)
{
   ...
```

And have tried something this

```
if (int callID = getCallIndex(roomID) >= 0)
{
    ...
```

But it gives a compiler error.

Is it possible to instantiate and set a variable within an if() statement?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If you need that value at several places it's even better to declare it outside of the `if`.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve

Comment: The code is needed in several, but not all if() statements, which are nested within if()/else() statements themselves.

The call ID is not always relevant to all if() statements

edit: whoops, [enter] submits...

Comment: That sounds as if you should refactor your code since it's currently spaghetti code. Use classes and methods and avoid deeply nested `if`s. Somtimes you can do that by pre-checking variables(f.e. on  illegal method arguments throw exceptions immediately) or by reversing conditions.

Comment: do you need CallID again? or are you just checking it is >=0?

Comment: If you find yourself replicating the same piece of code, then it sounds like you need to refactor. If you can provide more of the code you're writing, then we can demonstrate how it can be done.

Comment: If you just wanna check the value returned by `static int getCallIndex(...)`, you don't need to assign it to a variable. Just equate the returned value. Change the `if` statement to `if(get CallIndex(roomID)>=0){...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In contrast to a `for`-loop the expression within the if-statement is a single expression that evaulates to `true` or `false`. An assignement however evaluates to the assigned value which is an `int` in your example. In the `for`-loop however you can make such assignmenets as you can include blocks of code instead of single-value expressions:

```
for(assignements; condition; actions)
```

As you can see the first parameter and the last one of the loop can also be several statements. The if-statement however expects a value instead of statement.

So this is not possible.

Answer (score 4):

You could do an assignment and a comparison within the if statement like this:

```
int callID;
if ((callID = getCallIndex(roomID)) >= 0)
{
}
```

but you still need to declare the `int callID` variable outside of the statement.

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, it is impossible to declare a variable inside of the codition of an `if` statement in C#.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't need the callID within the if, use the following:

```
if (getCallIndex(roomID) >= 0)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.You can use assignment inside an `if` condition.but you can't instantiate a variable inside it.

```
int callID;
if (callID=getCallIndex(roomID) >= 0)
{
    //do something.
}
```

so,it is not possible.